# Can there be or is there a Javascript addEventListener multiple arguments on single line helper function?

Tags: javascript, function, events, addeventlistener, dom-events

Can there be or is there something already, that can allow me to add multiple event listeners with multiple functions for different elements... on a single line?  Maybe an example will help me explain...

I am coming across situations like this in my code:

```
inputUrl.addEventListener ('keydown', saveOptions);
inputUrl.addEventListener ('keydown', resizeInput);

inputUrl.addEventListener ('keyup', saveOptions);
inputUrl.addEventListener ('keyup', resizeInput);

inputUrl.addEventListener ('click', saveOptions);
inputUrl.addEventListener ('click', resizeInput);

inputDirectory.addEventListener ('keydown', saveOptions);
inputDirectory.addEventListener ('keydown', resizeInput);

inputDirectory.addEventListener ('keyup', saveOptions);
inputDirectory.addEventListener ('keyup', resizeInput);

inputDirectory.addEventListener ('click', saveOptions);
inputDirectory.addEventListener ('click', resizeInput);
```

It seems it might be VERY nice to have something along the way of this to shorten the code!

```
makeEvents("inputUrl,inputDirectory|saveOptions,resizeInput|keydown,keyup,click")
```

I hope this makes sense.  Any ideas?  If something like this already exists I would like to know.  Otherwise maybe I could make a helper function (called makeEvents, or something), that would split the string, and for each element, then each function, attach each event?

I know my existing code logic doesn't make perfect sense at the moment, but I am mostly curious if this could be easily done or already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery can bind multiple events to multiple elements

```
$(inputUrl).add(inputDirectory).bind("keydown, keyup, click", function(){
     resizeInput(this);     
     saveOptions(this);
});
```

Comment: Assuming the OP can use jQuery this is a good solution. My answer assumed you needed javascript specifically and could not use jQuery.

Comment: I like this idea, but not sure I'm ready to use/learn jquery.  It seems easy enough to just include the jquery file and try it out.  I will try this because it seems like the most managable method and quickest to expand on.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't be worried about jQuery, it is as simple as just including the script and then using it where you need it. The documentation on it is really good as well http://docs.jquery.com/ . Of course, if you find yourself stuck just come back and post another question. The jQuery ones get answered pretty fast.

Comment: I have started using jQuery, and it is pretty exciting so far!  Although I will make sure that I don't overuse it, I will use it enough to make it worth including the file.  I do like all the examples they provide as well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
inputUrl.addEventListener ('keyup', function() { saveOptions(); resizeInput(); });
```

This way the 'keyup' event will call both functions and you have more control over the order that they are called in.

Comment: This is a nice idea, and it would save half the space.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you that someone invented functions

```
function setupEvents(element, action)
{
    element.addEventListener("keydown", action);
    element.addEventListener("keyup", action);
    element.addEventListener("click", action);
}

function setupActions(element)
{
    setupEvents(element, saveOptions);
    setupEvents(element, resizeInput);
}

setupActions(inputUrl);
setupActions(inputDirectory);
```

Comment: This seems like a manageable solution, and is what I'm used to.  It might grow larger though when things get more complex.  Thanks.